# Using the nextSyncToken as option for the syncToken in listCalendarList or listEvents returns the same result

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-client

In the Google Calendar API v 2.2.2 using getNextSyncToken returns the same nextSyncToken, causing an infinite loop when trying to retrieve all changes.

```
$next = $this->service->calendarList->listCalendarList()->getNextSyncToken();
$this->service->calendarList->listCalendarList(['syncToken'=>$next]);
```

What is the correct way to use this?

Comment: Have you try the example presented in [this blog (Calendar as a Service in PHP? Easy, with Google Calendar API!)](https://www.sitepoint.com/calendar-as-a-service-in-php-easy-with-google-calendar-api/)?

Answer (score 0):

The sync token only changes when something on the calendar changed so this is expected.

The way sync should work:

- send the first request with no sync token
- paginate through the results using the page token until there is no more page token, then save the sync token from the last page
- when you want to refresh your events (for example after receiving a push notification or after 24 hours since the last sync) provide the sync token on the request to get the newly modified entities